# Storing the variable in multiple blocks

Tags: javascript

I am performing several `http` requests via `axios` to fetch some data from my api. Therefore I am using an `array`called `Info` which contains all the information (IDs) that should be passed to the request. It looks like this:

```
var value;
Promise.all(Info.map(i => {
          this.value = i;
            return axios.get('http://API -Address'+i)
```

And of course I am handling the response with chained method `.then()`. However the variable `i` exists obviously just in the pre `.then()` block. But I need it in the `.then` block as well, since I am pushing all the `response data` into `anotherArray` and want to be able to distinguish between these through passing the `i` variable to each result which comes from a particular request.

```
.then(results => {
            results.map(res => {
              let val = this.value;
              anotherArray.push({...res.data, 'id': val});
           })
})
```

According to my logic the `value` variable should be updated and set equal to the actual `i`. Thereafter the temporal variable `val` will be set equal to `value` and passed into the `anotherArray`. At the end I want to have something like:

```
[
 {data: "someData", id: 1},
 {data: "someOtherData, id: 2}
]
```

And it works so far but with one lack, the variable `value` contains the value of the last element of the `Info` array instead of particular value for each request. That means I am getting the same ID for each data in my `anotherArray` and I can't distinguish between the elements.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `i` instead? What was the error? I can't remember but I think that the closure should include it

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `value` variable each time the `.map` loop is running.

Also your promises aren't guaranteed to return in order, so you'll need a way to lookup each value. You really will want a way to determine that ID by the response object itself since you are executing them all at once.

Comment: You are obviously right, but at the moment I don't have this possibility :(